# Get Distinct Parent Items using Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda, distinct

I have the following three classes;

```
public class City
{
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public Region Region { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Region
{
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have populated a City List object to contain a number of cities, of which each have a Region and a Country.

Now I want to get a list of all countries for all cities.  I've tried the following;

```
List<City> CityObjectList = GetAllCity();
CityObjectList.Select(r => r.Region).ToList().Select(c => c.Country).ToList();
```

However, all I get back is all the countries.  How can I get the distinct countries ?

Comment: _"populated the City object to contain a number of cities"_ i don't see a collection in `City`.

Comment: @Ahmad I tried Select(r => r.Region).ToList().Select(c => c.Country).Distinct().ToList(); but didn't work

Comment: the answer below should be sufficient ... you don't need the ToList() as Select already returns an IEnumerable ... thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
var allCityCountries = CityObjectList.Select(c => c.Region.Country).ToList();
```

This list is not distinct. To make the countries unique you could either override `Equals` + `GetHashCode` in `Country`, implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<Country>` for `Enumerable.Disinct` or use `GroupBy`(slowest but easiest  option):

```
var distinctCountries = CityObjectList
    .Select(c => c.Region.Country)
    .GroupBy(c => c.CountryCode)
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToList();
```

The `IEqualityComparer<T>` way:

```
class CountryCodeComparer : IEqualityComparer<Country>
{
    public bool Equals(Country x, Country y)
    {
        if(object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if(x == null || y == null) return false;
        return x.CountryCode == y.CountryCode;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Country obj)
    {
        return obj == null ? 0 : obj.CountryCode == null ? 0 : obj.CountryCode.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now you can use `Distinct` with an instance of it:

```
var comparer = new CountryCodeComparer();
distinctCountries = CityObjectList.Select(c => c.Region.Country).Distinct(comparer).ToList();
```

Comment: Worked perfectly using your your GroupBy example.  Thank you.